# increment of list elements in a certain pattern

Tags: python, list

I have a list for example:
`[1,2,3,4]`
I want to have ten repeats of the list, and every element increase by  1 than the previous element like:
`[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6................40 elements]`

Comment: Please share the attempts - `code` that you've tried and where do you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the previous answers!
The closest answer I got so far:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
n = 4 #number of elements in the list
newList = [ ]
for i in range(10):
    for element in list:
        newList.append(element + i*n)
print(newList)
print(len(newList))
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]

40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst = [i + j for i in range(9) for j in temp]
print(lst)

# which equals to this:
temp = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst2 = []
for i in range(9):
    for j in temp:
        lst2.append(i + j)
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 0):

plz have a look.  I don't think it goes upto [1,2,..40] , only goes upto[1,2,.. 14].

At each iteration you are increasing the value by 1 so, after 10 times repeating every no in the array will be increased by 10. So 4 will be 14 which will be the last element not 40.
Here's my code according to your requirement,

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
answer = [ ]
for i in range(11):
    for element in arr:
        answer.append(element + i)
print(answer)
```